# Converting MemoryStream to String with JSON

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm having difficulty using using MemoryStream to manage strings.

Specifically, I'm playing with JSON without using built in serialisation/deserialisation methods.

When using NewtonSoft JSON writer, it's simple enough and it takes a TextWriter so writing is something like this with a string builder:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        using (newton.JsonWriter writer=new newton.JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
            writer.WriteValue("Neil");
            writer.WriteEnd();
            writer.Flush();
            System.Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
```

But when I'm trying to use the new .net Core 3.x, it doesn't take a TextWriter, but a Stream or IBufferWriter. Not exactly knowing how to use the IBufferWriter, the only way I could get it to convert the stream to a string was the following, which seems quite clunky in comparison. Is there a better way than setting the position, creating a new reader and reading to end as below?

Either a better way to convert memory stream to string or using IBufferWriter?

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(ms);
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
        writer.WriteStringValue("Neil");
        writer.WriteEndObject();
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        string output = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=netframework-4.8) on the memory stream to turn it into an array of UTF-8 bytes, which can then be converted to a string with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
Utf8JsonWriter writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(ms);
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
writer.WriteStringValue("Neil");
writer.WriteEndObject();
writer.Flush();
ms.Close();
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the benefit of a stream rather than a writer? it seems so much easier the other way. btw, and I cannot find any documentation on IBufferWriter

Comment: @Neil You could create a [`ArrayBufferWriter<byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1?view=netcore-3.1) for writing as well. Then you can use `WrittenMemory.ToArray()` to get the UTF 8 byte array. I don't really know much about `IBufferWriter` either except that the fact that it is a newer API, which is why I used `MemoryStream` in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A memory efficient approach can be done by using the [`Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) library, which provides a `RecyclableMemoryStream` type that implements [`IBufferWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.ibufferwriter-1) and a handy `GetReadOnlySequence` method that will avoid the allocation of a new array by not having to call `ToArray`.

The following code makes use of the library with your last example:

```cs
using Microsoft.IO;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

...
// Declare this as a field of your class.
private static readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager Manager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
...

using (var ms = (RecyclableMemoryStream)Manager.GetStream())
{
    using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter((IBufferWriter<byte>)ms))
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
        writer.WriteStringValue("Neil");
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetReadOnlySequence());
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

The [`Encoding.GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions.getstring) method that accepts a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` is an extension method provided by [`EncodingExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions), which is available on .NET 5+.

`RecyclableMemoryStream` also provides a `GetSpan` method that can be used when the above extension method is not available, in which case some tweaks to the code around `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` will be needed in order to provide a `Span<byte>` instead:

```cs
ms.Position = 0;
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetSpan().Slice(0, (int)ms.Length))
```

For more details about the use and configuration of this library, I recommend you to take a look at [its documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream#microsoftiorecyclablememorystream-).